# PLSQL: Padding numbers and numeric conversion with truncation

Tags: oracle, plsql, padding, truncate

I am trying to get desired output with padded zeroes and few more conditions as defined below based on field length and decimal length. I have reached part of solution but not completely. Here are my requirements.

For a given number 179.237, in the output i want total length to be 12 with only 2 decimal positions. also the decimal point has to be removed.

**Given input** (Sample but can be of any length):

```
179.237
```

**Expected Output** (total length 12 with 2 decimals at end i.e.truncate and decimal point to be removed):

```
000000017923
```

At the same time if given number is having less decimal values or none (for ex: 179.2, i should get output as below (with right padded zero).

```
000000017920
```

**My code:**

```
SELECT LPAD(TRIM(RPAD(TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(179.237,'.')),9999999999.00),12)),12,'0') from dual;
```

**My Output:**

```
000000179237
```

So i think i missed the truncate part in this. Also please advise if this code can be simplified as i am having too many functions. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by 100 then `TRUNC`ate to remove any remaining decimals and use `TO_CHAR` with the format mask `000000000000`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(179.237*100),'000000000000') AS VALUE
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE
------------
000000017923
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the simple solution :)